# intl package and date formatting strange behaviour

Tags: internationalization, dart, intl

I start to use intl package in my dart project.
After start to use this package i use this code:

```
  DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
  var formatter = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
  String nowFormatted = formatter.format(now);
```

And it works correctly.
After i use intl i obtain this message in log:

```
Uncaught LocaleDataException: Locale data has not been initialized, call initializeDateFormatting(<locale>).
```

I cannot understand why i should pass locale in this code snippet

Comment: it is contained in date_format.dart. in the header of the file i see part of intl;

Comment: @ThierryTemplier the Dart `intl` is not related to the JS `intl`.

Comment: Your code prints `2016-03-23T10:39:03Z` for me. Which line causes your exception? What version of `intl` is listed in your `pubspec.lock` file?

Answer (score 56):

### intl: ^0.15.7

I've the same issue to the current `Intl` version so I've solved with

these imports:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
```

and the code:

```
initializeDateFormatting();
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
var dateString = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(now);
final String configFileName = 'lastConfig.$dateString.json';
```

Comment: This `initializeDateFormatting()` with no arguments does not work in latest version `intl: ^0.16.1`. Any solution?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher Have you tried for example something like : `initializeDateFormatting('de_DE', null)`

Comment: @FaizanMubasher, I had the same sure. Make sure that you have this import: `import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';`, because `initializeDateFormatting` is included is several files.

Comment: It must be `date_symbol_data_local` (2nd parameter ignored) not `date_symbol_data_file`!

Comment: `initializeDateFormatting` is a future, so you must `await initializeDateFormatting()` or `initializeDateFormatting().then((_) => runMyCode())` to avoid unexpected results (otherwise it might not actually finish initialising before you use DateFormat)

Comment: It's required two arguments compulsory.

Comment: @PratikButani In the far 2019  the release 0.15.7 didnt need two args. So why vote negative a correct answer that worked great?

Comment: Definitely not worked great. but do you think this answer is useful now?

Comment: @PratikButani Yes it is. There is always people who need the correct code for  old library release. Thats the stackoverflow phylosophy , you should know it.

Comment: @JamesAllen not necessarily, it just assigns a mapping to variable:)

Answer (score 24):

Verify your imports:

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Set [initializeDateFormatting](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/date_symbol_data_http_request/availableLocalesForDateFormatting.html) according to your language, example:

```
initializeDateFormatting('pt_BR', null);
```

Comment: On Intlˆ0.18, we are no longer able use null on the url param

Answer (score 23):

If you encounter this problem, write `initializeDateFormatting('az');` top of "Material App". I searched for 1 hour and nobody wrote it clearly.

it is really solved.
[image]

Answer (score 14):

Use this function in main

```
initializeDateFormatting();
```

and import like this

`import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';`

Comment: This was exactly it for me. The import giving me the error was "import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_file.dart';"

Answer (score 11):

I have solved this use in this way:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
var formatter = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", 'en');
String nowFormatted = formatter.format(now);
```

But I have to make this to my dart file used to configure itnl support:

```
library translation_helper;

import 'dart:async';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import '../../resources/messages_all.dart';


void setupLanguage(){
  //var germanDatesFuture = initializeDateFormatting('de_DE', null);
  var enDatesFuture = initializeDateFormatting('en', null);
  var germanMessagesFuture = initializeMessages('de');
  var englishMessagesFuture = initializeMessages('en');
  var italianMessagesFuture = initializeMessages('it');
  var polishMessagesFuture = initializeMessages('pl');
  Future
      .wait([
    enDatesFuture,
    germanMessagesFuture,
    englishMessagesFuture,
    italianMessagesFuture,
    polishMessagesFuture
  ]);
}
```

Before I was missing:

```
 var enDatesFuture = initializeDateFormatting('en', null);
```

For more info I use:

- dart 1.15.0
- intl 0.12.7

Comment: Interesting. Why do you need that while it worked for me without. What OS are you using?

Comment: Boring OSX last version -_-

Comment: Yes, you have to initialize the format for a particular locale before you can use it. In some cases the data is already loaded, but in others (most commonly messages, where the data can take up a lot of space) it might need to load the data before it can be used. Typically you wouldn't initialize all the messages for every locale, just the one for your user's locale.

Comment: Where do you put the configuration?

Answer (score 7):

- In your pubspec.yaml, add this dependencie package: `intl:`
- In your highest StatefulWidget (in your dart file), add these imports:

```
    import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
    import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
```

- In its State, override initState add :

```
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        initializeDateFormatting(); //very important
      }
```

- And the code:

```
     DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
     var formatter = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
     String nowFormatted = formatter.format(now);
```

Answer (score 6):

There's no need to call *initializeDateFormatting* directly from your code. Just call *load* method of app's localization delegates.

So you specify delegates like this:

```dart
final localizationsDelegates = <LocalizationsDelegate>[
  AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
  GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  CupertinoLocalizationsDelegate()
];

...

  MaterialApp(
    localizationsDelegates: localizationsDelegates,
  )
```

And pre-load them with system's locale:

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

...

for (final delegate in localizationsDelegates) {
  await delegate.load(ui.Locale(ui.window.locale.languageCode));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

My issue was that I was getting error specifically for the "en_US" Locale even when I was not particularly using it. But I solved it by:

```
initializeDateFormatting('en', null);
initializeDateFormatting('en_US,', null);
```

Answer (score 5):

In your class with `MaterialApp` add this code

```
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';

@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();`enter code here`
    initializeDateFormatting();
  }
```

Comment: this threw: "Unsupported operation: Cannot modify unmodifiable map" error... am stuck with this issue now...

Comment: @HaKim you need to add above mentioned code in the widget in which you are using Intl package

Answer (score 1):

To initialize the date format as per the system locale.

```
import 'package:intl/intl_standalone.dart'; // For standlone app
import 'package:intl/intl_browser.dart'; // For standlone app
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
...
await initializeDateFormatting(await findSystemLocale(), null);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Depending on intl: ^0.18.0

**Just add this line in the method that listens to each time the locale changes**

```
Intl.defaultLocale = languageCode;
```

package: https://pub.dev/packages/intl

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. But, only when switching between locales ('en' and 'si') within the app. None of the other solutions worked for me. So I just came up with this dumbest solution, and it worked. Just wrapped date-formatting in a try-catch block while `initializeDateFormatting()` is being called inside the catch block

```
String  date(DateTime date, String _languageCode) {
    try {
        var formatter = new DateFormat.yMMMMd(_languageCode);
        return formatter.format(date);
    } catch(e) {
        initializeDateFormatting();
        var formatter = new DateFormat.yMMMMd(_languageCode);
        return formatter.format(date);
    }
}
```