# Dart DateFormat not using system's locale automatically

Tags: flutter, dart, time

I have the following code running on Flutter:

```dart
void main() async {
  await initializeDateFormatting();
...

 () async {
   await findSystemLocale().then((locale) {
     print(locale);
   });
   print(DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(DateTime.now()));
   print(DateFormat.MMMMd().format(DateTime.now()));   
 },
```

And I get the follwing output on my Android 9 Emulator:

> I/flutter ( 4239): pt_BR
>   I/flutter ( 4239): January 9, 2020
>   I/flutter ( 4239): January 9
>   I/flutter ( 4239): Tap on a Card!

It's detecting correctly that the system is configured as `pt_BR` (Portuguese/Brazil), but it's output is as if it was `en_US`.

I could swear that changing the system's language was automatically changing the `DateFormat` output, but now it doesn't anymore and I didn't upgrade the code, neither change it. I already tried to restart the device, reinstall the app, but nothing changes.

I know I can force the `locale` into the `DateFormat` but I just **want to learn on how to do it right and what am I doing wrong.**

If I do this instead:

```dart
void main() async {
  await initializeDateFormatting();
  Intl.defaultLocale = await findSystemLocale();
```

Hard setting the `defaultLocale` on initialization, it works as expected, so I am guessing the `defaultLocale` isn't being loaded automatically. This might have to do with the fact that I am running my code inside a new Zone with:

```dart
  await initializeDateFormatting();
  Intl.defaultLocale = await findSystemLocale();

  runZoned(
    () => runApp(MyApp()),
    onError: Crashlytics.instance.recordError,
    zoneSpecification: ZoneSpecification(
      print: (self, parent, zone, message) {
        if (isDebug) { // we only print in a debug build.
          parent.print(zone, message);
        }
      },
    ),
  );
```

If so, how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe this is correct? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174033/intl-package-and-date-formatting-strange-behaviour